# Storing an Image with php?

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to store an Image in my website so I can use it easily but I found this php code from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) and I can't quite make much sense of it.. I'm just starting php and I dont quite know what to change and what to keep.. I'd greatly appreciate it if you could explain this a little better for me, thanks.

```
    <?php
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISSECTION:**

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
```

**The above checks the mime-type of the uploaded image to the ones allowed**

---

```
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
```

**Specifies maximum size and also checks if the file extension is in the array $extension**

---

{

```
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
```

**Checks for an upload error, and prints out the return code.**

---

```
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
```

**Echoes out the attributes of the uploaded file.**

---

```
 if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
```

**If file exists on the `upload/` folder on the server, echoes out that that particular file already exists**

---

```
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
}
```

**If it doesn't already exist in the upload folder on the server, it is copied to it.**

---

```
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
```

**Invalid if it failed the checking of file type, extension, size etc in the steps 1 and 2**

Answer (score 2):

I'll break this down a bit:

```
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
```

We're only going to allow jpg, jpeg, gif and png file uploads.  This array holds our allowed extensions.  You could add other extensions here if you wanted to.

```
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
```

This does a couple of things.  First, you need to realize that when a file is uploaded to PHP it's accessed by the $_FILES array.  $_FILES['file']['name'] contains the filename of the uploaded file.  To get the extension from the file name the name is being converted to an array with explode, splitting it up on the '.' character.  So if the file was called image.jpg you'd end up with an array ('image', 'jpg').  The end() function takes the last element of the array.  So in this example you'd end up with 'jpg'.

```
> if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") ||
> ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"]
> == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) && in_array($extension,
> $allowedExts))
```

This is just checking that the file type is one of 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', or 'image/pjpeg' and that it's under 20000 bytes and that the file extension is in the $allowedExts array.

Assuming it is the following line checks for an error code and prints it out if there's an upload error:

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
```

And if there's no error (i.e. $_FILES['file']['error'] <= 0) then it outputs some information about the upload and then checks for existence of the file in the /uploads directory with the name of the upload:

```
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
```

and then prints out an error if the file already exists.

If the file doesn't already exist then it copies the file from the temporary location that it gets placed in when it's uploaded and moves it to the /upload directory with the appropriate file name.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain what you want to delete or keep either, but, I can explain what is being done in the code.

This code assumes that you have an html chunk that defines input of a type="file" with name="file".

The parameters passed to on submission of the file are stored in $_FILES[].  $_FILES has lots of informationincluding the file type, size, error information.

The first line  indentifies an array to be used later of valid image file extensions.

The first if statement checks to determine if the file being passed is a valid file format using mime type checking, checks the extension is valid, and if the size is acceptable.  If this is not a valid file type, the code jumps to the bottom of the code and creates an error message.  You might want to change the size of the file that is acceptable.

If there is an error,  the messages is returned.
If no erro, then this code prints out the statistics about the file being upload.   It provides the file name, file type, file size and a temporary name for the file.

The code checks to see if the file has already been loaded in the "upload/" directory.   You may want to change where the files are stored, you would change this to check the directory where you are going to be storing your images.

If it finds the file is already on the server, it gives a warning message and processing stops.   You might like to change this to rename the file and continue processing.

If the file is not already on the server, the next line:
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

moves the content from the temporary storage location to the permanent directory "upload/" and prints that the upload was complete.

Note: This is a really simplistic version of the upload process ... though valid.  You might want to
:
1) Adjust this so it will not fail if someone used the extensions .GIF, JPG, or PNG and some cameras and people store things with uppercase.   It might be nice to recognize the extension in upper and lower case.
2) Rename old files or the newly uploaded file if you think you might like to save old copies of files.
3) Update the file size quite a lot, the current file size is pretty small

Comment: ohhh thats what `file` is, it's the input. thats helpful.. but what about `tmp_name` and `name`?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just try with a basic breakdown of the code.

`$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");` creates an array containing the permitted file extensions (jpg, jpeg, gif and png".

`$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));` will extract the file extension of the file being uploaded, saving that value in the variable $extension.

Following block is explained below:

```
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
```

This if condition checks the extensions of the file being uploaded. If the file is a gif, or a jpeg or a png AND less than 20000 bytes AND the extension is found in the array of allowed extension, the condition is true. If it is false, the second if clause runs and the code will print an error depending on what thing failed. You can find a comprehensive list of PHP $_FILES errors here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php.

If the if clause checking the file extension and size turned out to be true, this code is executed:

```
else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
```

This block of code prints out the file name, type, size and (eventual?) temporal files that are stored on the server to the user.

After performing that piece of code, this follows:

```
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
```

Basically this first checks if the selected file already exists with the first if clause. If it exists, it states so and ends the script. If it doesn't already exist, it transfers the file and states the successful transfer.

The absolutely last else clause, `else{echo "Invalid file";}` looks like just a failsafe that will exit the script should something go terribly and horribly wrong.

This is a very simple file transfer script with almost zero security. If you wanna use this script be very careful as it could cause major issues if you let untrusted users use it.

I hope it was understandable.